# Potential should be same for zero current

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, passive-networks, voltage-source

[image]

In the above circuit, I have to adjust variable resistor R such that current across Load resistor RL should be zero.

Which means the voltage across RL should be same. Do i have to use KVL supernode concept here to find currents I1 and I2 in the two loops if so there will be more number of unknowns then required. How many different ways can this problem be approached ?

If I use KVL and assume i1 and i2 (clk wise) in the two loops
4i1 + 10i1 + 5i2 + Ri2 = 0
So do I have to make 4i1 = Ri2?  or 4i1=5i2?
What to do next to get i1 and i2? Should balanced bridge concept be used here?

Comment: Simply ensure that the resistance path to the left has the same values as the one to the right. If there's 14ohm on both sides then no current will flow through RL... There's nothing more to it and this schematic is completely artificial. In the real world where electronics actually exists as physical components, resistors come with a specified accuracy, so there is no easy way to avoid tiny stray currents.

Comment: Try removing the resistor RL and ensuring there will be no voltage across where it was connected. You can think of it as two voltage dividers.

Answer (score 1):

1. For zero current to flow through \$R_L\$, the voltage across it must be zero
2. If zero current flows across \$R_L\$, then the 10Ω and 4Ω form an *unloaded* voltage divider. And so do 5Ω and the adjustable \$R\$.
3. For the voltage across \$R_L\$ to be zero, the voltage in the middle of these voltage dividers needs to be equal.
4. You know the formula for voltage dividers (if not, you should look it up!), so that's just a matter of inserting an equality sign and solving for \$R\$.